# Database and Linux monitoring tool

Tags: shell, unix, user-interface

I want to create a tool which can monitor my processes (memory,cpu, status, etc) also database (backlogs etc). The processes run on Linux and use DB as oracle.
There are many various monitoring things to be added to this tool.

This will be reported on a local web.

So for this I have to create a GUI . 
In the background I will run shell script and sql script to fetch different type of data and will dump the data into a file.

**So in which language I should write the GUI ?**

The end user will be many around 10,000 +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from Java view server and web-based GUI (Flex/AJAX) or .NET GUI whichever you have more attitude to, web-based implementation will add slightly more load on server (extra layer on top of bare web service required for .NET).

And of cause the collector itself - Java server exposing XML/JSON/BinaryTCP interfaces to outer world. Any bash/perl script will be able to easily post into it using JSON.

Java is a best choice for any non-ultra-high-performance-and-low-latency software having to expose multiple heterogeneous interfaces as most of industrial quality building blocks will be available from the community for free and will nicely work together thanks to massive standardization efforts by the same community.

**References**

- [Servlet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html), a Java technology to serve client requests (HTTP and
  Web-service in particular)
- [JAX-WS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Web_Services), a Java technology used to
  expose SOAP Web-services over Servlet
- [Grails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grails_%28framework%29), an example of a Servlet-based Web framework, [Struts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts) and [JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) are other examples; these may accelerate development process if you do web-based GUI

Comment: Can you elaborate more and just show me some useful link to the above mentioned java items

Comment: can php be used to invoke the script on a unix different server

Comment: @Kimi - php can remote any command via ssh by http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is not a question about which language you **should** use, but which language you **can** use.

if the GUI you meant is a web-GUI, there are many languages could do the job. java, php, python, ruby... and the application/web server/container could be different depends on the technology you have chosen.

I would suggest doing it with the technology (language), which you know best.

Comment: I have never implemented a GUI, I know shell scripting and c++. So any thing which will help me create it and have the wow factor on the user will do.